# Algolia: searching multiple indices in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, advanced-search

I would like to set up algolia to search multiple indices in Laravel, using something simple like this.

```
Route::get('/search/{query}', function ($query) {
$queries = [
    [
        'indexName' => 'movies_index',
        'query' => $query,
        'hitsPerPage' => 3
    ],
    [
        'indexName' => 'directors',
        'query' => $query,
        'hitsPerPage' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'indexName' => 'screenwriters',
        'query' => $query,
        'hitsPerPage' => 10
    ]
];



var_dump($queries);});
```

But I'm a beginner in laravel and algolia as well so I'm not entirely sure how to go on about it.

Comment: are you using [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout) or the [Algolia PHP library](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php)?

Comment: @HCK Laravel scout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Algolia Docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/multiple-queries/#examples) states:

```php
// perform 3 queries in a single API call:
//  - 1st query targets index `categories`
//  - 2nd and 3rd queries target index `products`

$queries = [
  [
    'indexName' => 'categories',
    'query' => $myQueryString,
    'hitsPerPage' => 3
  ],
  [
    'indexName' => 'products',
    'query' => $myQueryString,
    'hitsPerPage' => 3,
    'facetFilters' => 'promotion'
  ],
  [
    'indexName' => 'products',
    'query' => $myQueryString,
    'hitsPerPage' => 10
  ]
];

$results = $client->multipleQueries($queries);

var_dump($results['results']);
```

---

Don't forget to initialize your `$client` first:

```php
$client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client('APP_ID', 'APP_KEY');
```